# How to access the data in a Nested JSON in ngContainer?

Tags: html, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to access some fields of a JSON Object for angular material expandable table, but when I access it by `'.'` or `['parameter']` the value reflects as undefined.

This is the code that I am using to access the Values inside my JSON Object. I am able to access just next keys of the JSON object but not able to access the keys of JSON in an array inside the JSON object.
Example: I can get case.email but I cannot access case.caseData[i].id as it throws `undefined` value.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="caseId" > 
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Case ID </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let case;index as i" > {{case.caseData[i] | json }} </td>
                    </ng-container>
```

this is the JSON I am trying to access the value of.

```
{
    "caseData": [
        {
        "enrollmentType": "Reimbursement",
        "id": "5cf"
    }
    ],
    "dateOfBirth": "2019-06-11",
    "email": "",
    "firstName": "THOMAS",
    "id": "5cfg",
    "lastName": "DEOTI",
    "phoneNumber": "555-555-5555",
    "totalCases": 5
}
```

I want to access `id` and `enrollmentType` in caseData for angular expandable table

Comment: Could you please add the version, that works?

Comment: Please create stackblitz and add a link here

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link of full code: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvffb1) . I am now able to access the values inside ```caseData``` variable but not able to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

I made you an example in this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj9h11

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link of full code: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvffb1)

Comment: The data passed to the table should be an array of rows. You cant use a nested array (an array of rows with rows in each row). You have to convert your array "patients" to have one entry per row.

Comment: So is that a limitation of Angular Mat Table? because I am able to iterate over an "array of rows with rows in each row" using datatable.net. Also, You are able to show only the first object of array in the patients JSON object and the second one is not visible(as per your stackblitz example). Why is the happening?

Comment: @ChiragSehra yes, I think this is a limitation of Angular Material. You can make a function that prepares the data in the appropiate format.